# Evaluating a string input for only "y" and "n" in Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, while-loop, try-catch

I am looking to write code that takes an input and looks for y or n. I am having a problem filtering out things that are not y or n and if the input is incorrect, that it goes and asks for the input again.

Here are a couple things I've tried:

```
while True:
    try:
        need_a_classlist = int(input("\nDo we need to make a classlist first? Y/N "))
    except ValueError or str(need_a_classlist).lower != ("y", "n"):
        print("\nOkay, let's make a classlist!")
        break
    else:
        print("\nInvalid Response, please type 'y' or 'n'.")
        continue
```

and:

```
if need_a_classlist == "y":
    def add_new_student(student):
        class_list.append(student)
        return class_list
    #get a number for a classlist
    number_of_students = int(input("\nHow many students in the class? "))
    #user input to add to class list
    while number_of_students > 0:
        new_student_name = input("\nWhat is the students name?  ").lower()
        if new_student_name.isalpha():
            add_new_student(new_student_name)
            print( "\n" + new_student_name.title() + " added to class list!")
            number_of_students -= 1
        if number_of_students == 0:
            break
#If they say no
elif need_a_classlist == "n":
    print("\nOkay let's move on to the seating chart.")
#If they put in something else
else:
    print("\nInvalid entry, please try again.")
```

but this does not repeat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
done = False
while not done:
    inp = input("Do we need to make a classlist first? (y/n):")
    if inp.lower() in ["y", "n"]:
        done = True
        #rest of your code
```

What I have done here is I have put the input checking code within a while loop, which repeats while the `done` variable is `False`. If the user enters valid input, then `done` becomes `True` and the repetition stops. If the user enters invalid input, then they are prompted again.